# Artifacts in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04

Tags: gnome, intel-graphics, 17.04, visual-artifacts, intel-cpu

I use Ubuntu 17.04 with GNOME DE and sometimes there are strange artifacts when i resize file explorer window - it turns into colored lines on black background for a moment (can't take a screenshot while resizing the window). Can it be fixed somehow?

CPU i5-7400 
GPU Intel HD630

Comment: Are you running with Nvidia video card? What drivers did you install?

Comment: No, only Intel HD

Comment: You should be able to use gnome-screenshot to take a timed screenshot while you're resizing a file explorer window. Just set the timer to 10-15 seconds and then start resizing a window.

Comment: Does it look like this one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99x_FzwrBgY